# (Proof) Analytic function have isolated zeros?

Tags: complex-analysis

A complex-polynomial of degree $n$ has $n$ roots, hence a complex power series can be thought of degree $\mid \mathbb{N} \mid$ and hence has countable many roots. I know my reasoning is not at all mathematically rigor, but can some prove the above question using same/similar argument.

Answer (score 1):

Can't prove it because it's false. $e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}$ has no roots.

That was an answer to the original version. It's hard to predict what the question's going to be when I finish this, but:

Yes, a non-trivial power series has at most countably many roots. This follows from the fact that the zeroes are isolated.

I suspect that the answer to what I suspect the question is is no, for at least two reasons: (i) II don't see how the fact that a polynomial has only $n$ roots implies directly that a power series has only countably many zeroes, and (ii) even if I did see how that goes I don't see how it would help: A countable set need not be isolated.

Comment: nice and simple example which I overlooked, nonetheless if I change the hypothesis from "equal" to "atmost", will it then be provable?

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh I have no idea what the new question is supposed to be - I don't see the word "equal" anywhere, so I don't know what change you mean.

Comment: I mean every power series has atmost $\mid \mathbb{N} \mid$ roots

Comment: Yes, provided you add the word "nonzero."  If it had uncountably many roots, they would have a limit point, so not be isolated.

Comment: @saulspatz What did you conjecture the word "nontrivial"  meant? (I considered "non-zero", decided "nontrivial" was better, since of course it's not non-zero everywhere...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry, I meant to direct the comment to ManishKummarSingh's last comment.  There's no need to bite my head off, in any event.